# Color grading basics

Tags: color-correction, color-grading

I am fairly experienced with video editing, but I know embarrassingly little about color grading. Can anyone recommend any resources that can help me get started?

(I typically use Premiere Pro)

Comment: What do you want to learn about? How to color correct? Which software to use? How to choose a grading "look"? How to implement that look?

Answer (score 3):

I would look at some of the tutorials on YouTube. There are plenty of them.

If you want to get into grading; you can jump right in as long as you are shooting RAW; or at the very least; 4:2:2.

If you're shooting 4:4:4; you have a lot of flexibility.

Resolve's DaVinci Line has some nice low cost entry options that include control surfaces; I personally use a Tangent Wave with Resolve to grade RED material; it's fast and very robust.

It's important you look into workflow, that is; are you applying filters; or merely manipulating the metadata XML; as with RED footage. Each camera/codec/software will have it's own unique pipeline in terms of how you grade.

I would invest in a Spyder; and calibrate your monitor. You want to grade in a room that is lit to 70% ambiance of your monitor's brightness. So your monitor shouldn't blind you. Your color temperature needs to match as well; so if your monitor is 5600K; make sure all the bulbs in your edit room are 5600K; or your eyes will play tricks on you.

But on YouTube there are plenty of in depth tutorials; just keyword davinci resolve tutorial and you'll see.